# SwiftSoup Parsing HTML issue

Tags: google-chrome, html-parsing, swiftsoup

I am building an IOS app where I search for specific keyword in google and then parsing the HTML data using SwiftSoup as string and then extracting the data I want from that string , everything work good but the problem is that for some key words the google result will be multiple pages and I can get the data for the first page only , so how can I get the data for all pages ????